# List ebay Items using API on my Mobile App with products affiliate link

Tags: laravel, flutter, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I have a Mobile APP that is developed in Flutter. I want to add a section in my app called "shop". In that section I am planning to list the items from Ebay with my affiliate code, so that if anyone buy any products there I get a small amount of commission.

My App backend is written in Php Laravel. I don't have too much Idea about Ebay API. can you please suggest me the right path? the API that will give me the list of items with a specific category and items buy link should be included with my affiliate code. So that I can list those items on my shop section.

Comment: Want to create product links with your affiliate code? Or is it your problem in displaying the product list?

Comment: I want to create product lists with my affiliate code using ebay API. is there any API what I call and that gives me the list of products and products links contains my affiliate code?

Comment: I think you should use it:
`https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/commerce/catalog/resources/product/methods/getProduct`
ebay developers